# What does the word ''but rather'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

In this following context, what does the words ''but rather'' mean?
Does it mean ''on the contrary''? or ''instead''?
How should I understand this sentence in simple way?

Please, explain this to me.
Thanks to All.

Context:

> For this reason it would be better, concerning this problem, not to
> assume the bloodless attitude of modern sham-civilization, but rather
> adopt a reverential attitude in trying to solve this problem and grasp
> it in its profundity

.

Source:
https://books.google.com/books/about/Collected_Wheel_Publications_Volume_XXVI.html?id=Dgc4BgAAQBAJ#v=onepage&q=Judaism.%20For%20this%20reason%20it%20would%20be%20better%2C%20concerning%20this%20problem%2C%20not%20to%20assume%20the%20bloodless%20attitude%20of%20modern%20sham-civilization%2C%20but%20rather%20adopt%20a%20reverential%20attitude%20in%20trying%20to%20solve%20this%20problem%20and%20grasp%20it%20in%20its%20profundity.&f=false

Comment: From [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/not-but-rather) **not ... but rather ...**  - *used to say that one thing is not true but a different thing is true.* Their usage example: *The problem is not their lack of funding, but rather their lack of planning.*

Comment: So here what meaning does the word 'rather'? Does it really need here? Isn't it enough only the word ''but''?Thanks @Fumble Finger.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but offhand I *think* it would always be "syntactically valid" to replace all such instances of ***but rather*** by just ***but***. That doesn't imply either choice is better or worse than the other (either in general, or in any given context). Also note that James' answer suggests replacing ***but rather*** by ***instead*** (irrelevantly starting a new sentence and putting the adverbial element *after* the relevant clause, rather than *before* it).

Answer (score 2):

Rougly "instead".  It is used to give advice:

> Better not to do X, but rather do Y

Means

> You should not do X.  You should do Y instead.